# how to show and hide the div on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In my application i have a html button where i need to hide few elements which are in div on button click and show the same elements on again click the same button i am able to hide the div but how can i again show the div elements.Belo is my html and jquery code

Html

```
<button type="button" id="btnsearch" style="background-color: white">Search</button>
<div id="Show"></div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        $("#Show").hide();
    });
```

Comment: use `toggle()` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#toggle").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="toggle">
</div>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .toggle() in jquery

```js
$("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        $("#Show").toggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnsearch" style="background-color: white">Search</button>
<div id="Show">ff</div>
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates, rather mark them as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for the task

```
 $("#btnsearch").click(function(){
    $("#Show").toggle();
  });
```

By using jquery toggle() function will automatically hide and show the targeted element `#Show`